# Showing div based on filled form field

Tags: jquery, forms, show-hide

I have this script where I use a slider to show some elements of a form. So far so good. The way I'm doing it is by having a slider (can't use a multistep form since it uses a plugin not allowing multistep forms, plus some graphic behaviors) and a button that goes to the next slider. So now I need that button (not part of the form) to show only if a certain field is filled.

I tried teh following, but it's not working, I assume some error but can't figure what. My code is as follows:

```
$('#clientname').change(function() {
    var clientVal = $("input").val() == '';
$(".next").hide();

if ($('#clientname').val() != '').show();

else

$('.next').hide();
});
```

and the html as follows:

```
<div class="b40-right">


                        <h3>The Basics</h3>
                        <div class="label"> Your Name (required)</div>
                        <div class="inputes"> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input id="clientname" type="text" name="your-name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40" /></span> </div>
                        <div class="label">Your Email (required)</div>
                        <div class="inputes">    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="text" name="your-email" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" size="40" /></span> </div>
                        <div class="label">Type of Business</div>
                        <div class="inputes">    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap type-of-business"><textarea name="type-of-business" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-textarea" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></span> </div>



                    </div>

                    <a class="next" href="javascript:stepcarousel.stepBy('mygallery2', 1)"><img id="nextbut1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/next.png" alt="" /></a>
```

any help on what am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach/solution? (I'm not a programmer as you may figure)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#clientname').change(function() {
       if ($(this).val().length === 0)
          $('.next').hide();
       else
          $('.next').show();
    });
});
```

Whenever the value of the input with ID clientname changes, we check the length of the value (the number of characters entered in the input). If the length is zero, we hide the button, otherwise we show it.

I also wrapped it in a DOM-ready callback to make sure that we don't try to add the change-event listener until we know that the element is present in the DOM.

**Edit:**

The above example could also be written even shorter, like this:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#clientname').change(function() {
        $('.next').toggle($(this).val().length !== 0);
    });
});​
```

**Demo:**

A fiddle to demonstrate the code: http://jsfiddle.net/uQyH9/

Comment: Christofer, thank you for the answer, but the div still shows by default, should I use display:none or something? I tried it but didn't work either, maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: @Fabio Yes, either you set the button to be hidden by default using CSS `display: none;` like you suggest, or you call `$('.next').hide();` the first thing you do in the DOM-ready callback. I'll put together an example in a fiddle in a second.

Comment: @Fabio Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot that toggle can take a number as initial parameter as well, therefor my first code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want the *Next* button to appear if all required fields are filled.

So first you must hide the *Next* button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').hide();
});
```

After that, you check for required fields' changes, and set a variable to true if all of required fields are filled. And show your *Next* button if that variable is true.

```
$("input.wpcf7-validates-as-required").change(function() {
    checkIfAllFieldsAreFilled();
});

function checkIfAllFieldsAreFilled(){
    var fieldsAreFilled = true;

    $("input.wpcf7-validates-as-required").each(function(){
        fieldsAreFilled &= ($(this).val() != '');
    });

    if(fieldsAreFilled){
        $('.next').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you 1.44mb, however the answer by Christofer was exact since the other divs weren't using required fields yes I need the same behavior. Thank you anyways, I'm sure your answer might be valuable for someone else :)

Comment: I see that there are two fields (name and email) using required attribute, not just one as you stated.